# How to pass current view to events ajax call in fullcallendar v5 basic version

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I need to pass current view to ajax call in any ajax call and every time calendar grid changed

```
events: {
url: "{{route('clientSessionData')}}",
extraParams: {
    current_view_type: vm.type, // in here I want to pass current view now I stored it in vue element
},
    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
data: {
},
error: function() {
    $('#script-warning').show();
},
success: function(){
    console.log("successful: You can now do your stuff here. You dont need ajax. Full Calendar will do the ajax call OK? "); 
    // calendar.render();  
},
color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
textColor: '#ffffff', // a non-ajax option,

},
```

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement. Why does the server care what view you're using in the frontend? It should just return the events relevant for that date. How the user chooses to show those visually should not be the server's concern. Anyway it isn't really possible because the AJAX call fires before, or at least in parallel with, the view change, so you can't get fullCalendar to tell you what the new view is, because it hasn't been loaded at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the FullCalendar v5 View as follows

```
calendar.view.name
```

For example `timeGridWeek`

is this what you are after?

Comment: thanks dear Irving: this give me the the old value, I think ajax call happen before calendar.view change

Comment: what triggers your Ajax call @AliMashl? calling in `datesSet` should give you the current view. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet